# hidden form element not bound?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it standard/intended behaviour that the value of a hidden form field is not bound to the view model (nor is a query string value)?

Example:

```
<%= Html.Hidden("test", "13" )%>
```

if my poco view model contains a property test it should be bound shouldn't it?! i have to set it explicitely in the controller at the moment which kind of defeats the objective doesn't it?

```
bla( formviewmodel m, string test)
{
    m.test = test;
}
```

any feedback appreciated. thanks!

christian

**Edit:**

I inspected the form values like this:

string[] t = Request.Form.AllKeys;

```
        for( int c = 0; c < Request.Form.AllKeys.Count(); c++ )
        {
            string[] x = Request.Form.GetValues(c);
        }
```

and it definatley contains the value of test.

Comment: Do you pass the formviewmodel to the view?

Comment: Yes I do and all the form fields plus the hidden once are initialised properly. the data are also posted (used firebug) but hidden values are not bound.

Comment: This is in a Html.BeginForm() correct?

Comment: There isn't a Test property on your FormViewModel? If so, it may be bound to that property instead of the second param.  You might try removing the FormViewModel from the params.  Inspect the FormValueCollection and put the results in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The value for the hidden field is taken from Modelstate.

That can be from the URL (Roting value) or from a post.

The second paramter for the helper is only the default if no data exists from route or post.

You probably want to use

```
<input type="hidden" value="<%=Model.Test%>" name="Test" >
```

I did not see a view where the Html.Hidden field makes sense yet.

Comment: I am sorry I must be missing something. When I use:  <%= Html.Hidden("Test", Model.Test)%> it produces this: <input id="Test" name="Test" value="7007" type="hidden">. This should be fine but it is not - Test is not bound! Test is posted (see firebug but NOT bound)